# Removing Bounds on Quicksort algorithm - JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort, bounds

How might one go about removing both bounds checks in the inner while loops found in the partition method of the code below?

I understand that the second while loop is redundant since a[lo] acts as sentinel, but simply removing it doesn't seem to work.

```
public class Quick {

    // This class should not be instantiated.
    private Quick() { }

    /**
     * Rearranges the array in ascending order, using the natural order.
     * @param a the array to be sorted
     */
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
        StdRandom.shuffle(a);
        sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    // quicksort the subarray from a[lo] to a[hi]
    private static void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) { 
        if (hi <= lo) return;
        int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
        sort(a, lo, j-1);
        sort(a, j+1, hi);
        assert isSorted(a, lo, hi);
    }

    // partition the subarray a[lo..hi] so that a[lo..j-1] <= a[j] <= a[j+1..hi]
    // and return the index j.

    private static int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
        int i = lo;
        int j = hi + 1;
        Comparable v = a[lo];
        while (true) { 

            // find item on lo to swap
            while (less(a[++i], v))
                if (i == hi) break;

            // find item on hi to swap
            while (less(v, a[--j]))
                if (j == lo) break;      

            // check if pointers cross
            if (i >= j) break;

            exch(a, i, j);
        }

        // put partitioning item v at a[j]
        exch(a, lo, j);

        // now, a[lo .. j-1] <= a[j] <= a[j+1 .. hi]
        return j;
    }

    /**
     * Rearranges the array so that a[k] contains the kth smallest key;
     * a[0] through a[k-1] are less than (or equal to) a[k]; and
     * a[k+1] through a[N-1] are greater than (or equal to) a[k].
     * @param a the array
     * @param k find the kth smallest
     */
    public static Comparable select(Comparable[] a, int k) {
        if (k < 0 || k >= a.length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Selected element out of bounds");
        }
        StdRandom.shuffle(a);
        int lo = 0, hi = a.length - 1;
        while (hi > lo) {
            int i = partition(a, lo, hi);
            if      (i > k) hi = i - 1;
            else if (i < k) lo = i + 1;
            else return a[i];
        }
        return a[lo];
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your assumption is wrong and both loops are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question. If you're asking if this

```
if (i == hi) break;
```

and this:

```
if (j == lo) break;
```

can be removed, then I answer no.

These checks are important, in particular when the array is already sorted. If you removed these checks, in case of a sorted array, `less(a[++i], v)` would never be `false`, and would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to evaluate `a[hi+1]`.

As for the second while loop, you need it as well as the first. The first while looks for the lowest index `i` where `a[i]>a[lo]`, and the second looks for the highest `j` where `a[j]<a[lo]`. These two indices are used for the swap.